# Why doesn't storybook use the same webpack config as in the project?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook

I have been using storybook for a while now but I still couldn't understand the reason behind storybook has its own webpack config.

For example, if I config an absolute path in `tsconfig.json`, I have to do the same thing for storybook.

Or if I want to use a loader for a file type, I have to do it again for storybook and it's kind of annoying.

Can anyone explain this or how did you overcome this hassle in your previous projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@nishkaush I have to post a comment for you to read. So I did resolve that (loader for svg) even it took a lot of my time. Take a look if you're interested.

```
webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(
      (rule) => rule.test && rule.test.test('.svg'),
    )
    fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      enforce: 'pre',
      loader: require.resolve('@svgr/webpack'),
    })

    return config
  },
```

You can put that in your storybook webpack config (`main.js`)

And this one for project webpack config:

```
webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      issuer: {
        test: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
      },
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    })

    return config
  },
```

Don't forget to install @svgr/webpack

Comment: I wish i had seen this before re-writing all my code but its always good to know for the future. Thanks a lot for taking time to write it all out!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue today. Storybook's webpack config uses `SVG-loader` whereas my webpack config uses `file-loader`.

So, even though using an SVG as an `img`'s `src` worked for my project, it didn't work for Storybook.

Really annoyed me.

Had to re-write all my icons that were using img tag to use inline SVG. Wasted Afternoon!

Comment: Please take a look at my comment above